# FULL TEXT SEARCH for multiple keywords

Tags: php, sql, full-text-search

I have a search place on my site which allows users to search for content.
Until today I was using LIKE function which did the job but took long time because of the database being big. This is how my code looked like:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE body LIKE '%how%' AND '%to%' AND '%code%' LIMIT 30"
```

To improve speed I found out that I could use FULL TEXT SEARCH and this is how my code looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (body) AGAINST ('+how +to +code' IN BOOLEAN MODE)LIMIT 30;
```

The problem is that returns rows but they are just random ones which have some of the words in it.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371951/how-to-make-a-multiple-column-mysql-fulltext-search-where-partial-words-are-matc/15372080#15372080 ? You may find an answer to your problem there.

Comment: Do you have a `FULLTEXT` index on it?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Yes, I do

Comment: My Engine is InnoDB and I have tried putting ft_min_word_len = 2 , when I run the sql I get zero rows if it have words with less than four characters

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL setup for the `ft_min_word_len`-variable. You are matching for 'to' which is 2 characters and by default the fulltext-index is configured to index only words with a length of 3.

Make sure that you rebuild your FULLTEXT-index on your `body`-column after changing the `ft_min_word_len`-value.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm gonna try to find the settings and see

Comment: It didn't work, phpmyadmin showes ft_min_word_len = 2, but whenever I have word with less than four characters it gives zero rows.